# log4j custom pattern in otroslogviewer

Tags: log4j, otroslogviewer

Hi I  tried using otroslogviewer for viewing my application logs.But  everytime I try loading the logs otroslogviewer gives an error message regarding the log4j custom pattern parsing

my log4j pattern  property is

```
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p: %d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}: %c.%M(): %m%n
```

Can anyone tell me the correct pattern format which I need to specify in my pattern property file in otroslogviewer

Comment: Hi. Can you paste here fragment of your log?

Comment: `INFO : 10-Oct-2014 11:30:09,178: com.tcs.sgv.acl.service.AccessControlServiceImpl.getAllUserELement(): in global service loggedinPost---100016 INFO : 10-Oct-2014 11:30:09,179: com.tcs.sgv.acl.service.AccessControlServiceImpl.getAllUserELement(): userId...103002 INFO : 10-Oct-2014 11:30:09,180: com.tcs.sgv.acl.service.AccessControlServiceImpl.getAllUserELement(): locale...en_US`

Comment: @Lalit_Bhanot Note that using [LogMX](http://www.logmx.com), you only have to copy/paste this Log4j Pattern into LogMX graphical interface to make it work (and uncheck "match minimal characters" for `%c` so that both "Class" and "Method" fields are parsed as expected)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your logs looks like:

```
INFO : 10-Oct-2014 11:30:09,178: com.tcs.sgv.acl.service.AccessControlServiceImpl.getAllUserELement(): in global service loggedinPost---100016 
INFO : 10-Oct-2014 11:30:09,179: com.tcs.sgv.acl.service.AccessControlServiceImpl.getAllUserELement(): userId...103002
INFO : 10-Oct-2014 11:30:09,180: com.tcs.sgv.acl.service.AccessControlServiceImpl.getAllUserELement(): locale...en_US –
```

You can use following log pattern (Menu Tools-> Show log4j pattern parser editor):

```
type=log4j
pattern=LEVEL : TIMESTAMP CLASS: MESSAGE
dateFormat=dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS
name=Stackoverflow example
charset=UTF-8
```

Unfortunately, class and method is separated by '.' and log viewer is not able to detect which dot in `com.tcs.sgv.acl.service.AccessControlServiceImpl.getAllUserELement()` is separating field `CLASS` from `METHOD`.